# Why is gravity not working on my character controller?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making an fps controller but I cannot apply gravity to the character. I have made an `ApplyGravity()` function. In the image below the y direction of the character is decreasing but the character itself is not moving.

Here is the character controller code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class FirstPersonController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Dependencies")]
    [SerializeField] private GameInput gameInput;

    [Header("Movement Parameters")]
    [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float sprintSpeed;

    [Header("Look Parameters")]
    [SerializeField] private Transform cameraFollowTransform;
    [SerializeField] private float lookSensitivity;
    [SerializeField] private float topClamp = 90.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float bottomClamp = -90.0f;

    [Header("Jumping Parameters")]
    [SerializeField] private float jumpForce;

    [Header("Gravity Parameters")]
    [SerializeField] private float gravityMultiplier = 3f;


    // player
    private CharacterController characterController;
    private float rotationVelocity;
    private bool isSprinting;
    
    // input
    private Vector2 inputVector;
    private Vector3 moveDirection;

    // gravity 
    private float gravityForce = -9.81f;
    private float velocity;

    // cinemachine
    private float cinemachineTargetPitch;

    private void Awake()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        ApplyGravity();
        HandleMovement();    
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        HandleCameraRotation();
    }

    private void HandleMovement()
    {
        inputVector = gameInput.GetMovementVectorNormalized();
        moveDirection = new Vector3(inputVector.x, 0f, inputVector.y);

        moveDirection = transform.right * inputVector.x + transform.forward * inputVector.y;

        float targetSpeed = CheckSprint() ? sprintSpeed : moveSpeed;
        float moveDistance = targetSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        characterController.Move(moveDirection * moveDistance);
    }

    private void HandleCameraRotation()
    {
        Vector2 inputVector = gameInput.GetLookVector();
        
        cinemachineTargetPitch += inputVector.y * lookSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        rotationVelocity = inputVector.x * lookSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

        cinemachineTargetPitch = ClampAngle(cinemachineTargetPitch, bottomClamp, topClamp);

        cameraFollowTransform.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(cinemachineTargetPitch, 0f, 0f);

        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotationVelocity);
    }

    private void ApplyGravity()
    {
        velocity += gravityForce * gravityMultiplier * Time.deltaTime;
        moveDirection.y = velocity;

        Debug.Log(moveDirection);
    }

    private bool CheckSprint()
    {
        if (gameInput.GetPLayerInputActions().Player.Sprint.inProgress)
        {
            isSprinting = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isSprinting = false;
        }

        return isSprinting;
    }

    private static float ClampAngle(float lfAngle, float lfMin, float lfMax)
    {
        if (lfAngle < -360f) lfAngle += 360f;
        if (lfAngle > 360f) lfAngle -= 360f;
        return Mathf.Clamp(lfAngle, lfMin, lfMax);
    }

    
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdSdh.png)

I am using the same principle for movement and camera rotation and they are working fine. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your call to `ApplyGravity` you are calling `HandleMovement`, which is immediately overwriting `moveDirection`:

```
moveDirection = new Vector3(inputVector.x, 0f, inputVector.y);
```

You need to apply the player's input *on top of* the existing `moveDirection` instance.

Comment: Hi, you were right. I moved ApplyGravity() inside HandleMovement() and everything is working perfectly. Thank you!